# How do I open a notebook, in Python code by path in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I'm surprised by the fact that I couldn't find an answer to this.

How can I open a `.ipynb` file in a new Jupyter lab tab by executing code in a cell just as if I'd launched it in the File Browser?

I'm currently using v2.2.8 of Jupyter Lab.

Comment: I think [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) allows this. You probably should update to at JupyterLab 3; how extensions are handled changed dramatically in JupyterLab 3.

Comment: I'm not in control of the server but thank you for the suggestion.